# How to user Next.JS middleware to secure an API

Tags: next-auth

I try to use Next.js middleware to secure an API. The goal is:

- When the user is authenticated and calls the API, execute the API
- When the user is not authenticated and calls the API, return 401.

First try: using the standard middleware from the examples:

```js
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";

/* This tells the middleware to only run on the routes that match the pattern. */
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/api/user/:path*", "/api/post/:path*", "/api/nextmiddleware"],
};
```

- When the user is authenticated and the /api/nextmiddleware is called, all is OK.
- When the user is **not** authenticated and the /api/nextmiddleware is called, I get a redirect to the login page.

This would be fine when calling a page but it is not so fine when we call an API, a 401 would be more appropriate.

So what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a custom middleware does help, as long as we use `getToken()` inside the middleware to get some info if we are authorized or not.

`getSession()` and `getServerSession()` do not seem to work inside a middleware.

working sample:

```js
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

/**
 * If the request contains a valid token, we call `NextResponse.next()`.
 * If not, we send back a 401
 * 
 * @param req The request object
 * 
 * @return A function that is called by the Next.js API.
 */
export default async function middleware(req) {
  console.log(`Next Middleware for API called: ${req.url}`);

  try {
    // try to get a token from the request
    const token = await getToken({ req });
    if (token) {
      // yay, token available, we are authenticated
      return NextResponse.next();
    } else {
      // oh noes, no token, no fun
      console.log("no token");

      // send back a 401
      return new NextResponse(
        JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: "no token" }),
        { status: 401, headers: { "content-type": "application/json" } }
      );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // omg, something really bad happened, send back a 500
    console.log(error);
    return new NextResponse(
      JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: error.message }),
      { status: 500, headers: { "content-type": "application/json" } }
    );
  }
}

/* This tells the middleware to only run on the routes that match the pattern. */
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/api/user/:path*", "/api/post/:path*", "/api/nextmiddleware"],
};
```